# How to find the integer part of big number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, arithmetic

How to calculate the integer part
$$\left \lfloor10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{-10^{10}}}}}} \right \rfloor ?$$
Does this equal $$10^{10^{10}}? $$
Both Maple and Mathematica fail with it.

PS. Unmotivated votes down are not a constructive answer.

Comment: @cirpis $-10^{10}\ne (-10)^{10}$

Comment: oh yeah, i remembered that like the moment i posted my nonsense :P

Comment: OP, it would indeed equal $10^{10^{10}}$, if $10^{-10^{10}}=0$.  However it is not zero, but a very small positive number.  In any case, it is hopeless to compute what you seek, because it will be larger than $10^{10^{10}}$, which itself has 10 trillion digits.

Comment: To go off of vadim123, it is more than the number of atoms in the observable universe.

Comment: @vadim123: Most of these digits may be zeros.

Comment: It seems that $10^{10^{10}}$ could be the only answer that might be feasible to prove. But see below.

Comment: I have just found that was asked [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79217/how-to-calculate-1010101010-1010). The right answer is $2811012357389$. I think of the deletion of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

${-10^{10}}$ is very negative, hence $10^{-10^{10}}$ is very close to $0$, hence $\alpha:=10^{10^{-10^{10}}}$ is very close to $1$. Hence we expect the number in question to be somewhat close to $10^{10^{10}}$ and it is no wonder that CAS fail (or would produce a 10 billion digit output if they did not fail). It looks like our only chance to obtain a definite answer seems to be that we are lucky enough to show that
$10^{10^{10^{\alpha}}}$ is in a suitable interval of length at most $1$

**Lemma.** If $a<b<a+\log \frac{3}{\ln 10}$, then $10^a+\ln 10\cdot (b-a)10^a<10^b<10^a+3(b-a)10^a$.

*Proof.* Let $f(x)=10^x$. Then $f'(x)=\ln 10\cdot 10^x>0$. 
From the MVT we have 
$$\frac{10^b-10^a}{b-a}=f'(\xi)$$
for some intermediate $\xi$. The claim follows from $\ln10\cdot10^a=f'(a)<f'(\xi)<f'(a+\log\frac{3}{\ln 10})=3\cdot 10^a$. $_\square$

For the applicability of the lemma in what follows, note that $\log\frac 3{\ln 10}\approx 0.1149$.

First we find 
$$\tag2 1+\ln 10\cdot 10^{-10^{10}}<\alpha<1+3\cdot 10^{-10^{10}}.$$
From this,
$$\tag3 10+10(\ln 10)^2\cdot 10^{-10^{10}}<10^\alpha<10+90\cdot10^{-10^{10}}.$$
Next
$$ \tag4 10^{10}+10^{10}(\ln 10)^3\cdot 10^{-10^{10}}<10^{10^\alpha}<10^{10}+270000000000\cdot 10^{-10^{10}}.$$
Finally,
$$ \tag5 10^{10^{10}}+10000000000(\ln 10)^4<10^{10^{10^\alpha}}<10^{10^{10}}+810000000000.$$
Considering the size of the numbers involved, this is very close to the desired result - and yet so far away.
Can this be imrpoved? Well, it seems that we need to replace $3$ in the lemma with a number $c$ much closer to $\ln 10$ - in fact so close that $10^{10}c^4<\lceil10^{10}(\ln10)^4\rceil$. To acchieve this, we need something like $c<\ln10+10^{-13}$. Then $\log\frac{c}{\ln 10}\approx 1.88\cdot 10^{-14}$.

So we try the 
**Improved lemma.** Let $c=\ln 10+10^{-13}$. If $a<b<a+\log\frac{c}{\ln 10}$, then 
$$10^a+\ln 10 \cdot (b-a)10^a<10^b<10^a+c(b-a)10^a. $$

(Proof as above). We can repeat the steos above, noting that even $10^{10}c^310^{-10^{10}}$ is small enough (namely $\ll 10^{-14}$), so that this time we obtain 
$$ 10^{10^{10}}+10^{10}(\ln10)^4<10^{10^{10^\alpha}}<10^{10^{10}}+10^{10}c^4<\left\lceil10^{10^{10}}+10^{10}(\ln10)^4\right\rceil.$$
We conclude that
$$ \left\lfloor10^{10^{10^ {10^{10^{-10^{10}}}}}}\right\rfloor=10^{10^{10}}+\left\lfloor10^{10}(\ln 10)^4\right\rfloor =10^{10^{10}}+281101235738.$$

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen : Many thanks from me to you for your deep answer. I need some time to think about that.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen : Deep thought. You catch the heart of the problem.

Comment: I have just found that was asked [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79217/how-to-calculate-1010101010-1010). The right answer is $2811012357389$.